# Traversal of doubly-linked, bi-directional n-tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a data structure that maps multiple splicing isoforms of genes, meaning that each element of the graph could be predecessor or successor of any other element (excluding itself).
Structures might be A-B-C-D, A-C-E, and so on.

To represent that, I read the data files into an element

```
class El {
  vector<El*> left, right;
  T content;
};
```

so every element E contains is predecessors and successors, while the predecessors and successors also link back to E. This is necessary to construct the structures. It will be necessary to start traversing from any node of the structure for searching reasons, but this will lead to infinite circles when traversing with simple width or breadth first methods (here: start with C; traverse left: (B, A), (A); traverse right from A: (C, E), (B, C,...), traverse left from C: (B, A),...)

Wrong code (infinite circles):

```
vector<El*> startingpoints;

void traverse(El* el = nullptr) {
  if (el == nullptr) {
    for (auto& node : startingpoints) {
      traverse(node);
    }
  }
  else {
    for (auto& ltEl : el->left) {
      traverse(ltEl);
    }
    std::cout << *El;
    for (auto& rtEl : el->right) {
      traverse(rtEl);
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody suggest a proper method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flag to class El. flag=0 indicates you have not handled this node yet, while 1 indicates the node have been handles and thus stop.

Comment: Ah, thanks... that's a great idea. As I have to access the method multiple times I modified it as follows, and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

My current method, based on Min Fu's idea:

```
class El {
  vector<El*> left, right;
  uint runID; // init to 0
  T content;
};

vector<El*> startpoints;

void traverse(El* el = nullptr) {
  static uint runID = 1;
  if (el == nullptr) {
    for (auto& node : startingpoints) {
      traverse(node);
      runID++;
    }
  }
  else {
    el->runID = runID;
      // predecessors
    for (auto& ltEl : el->left) {
      if (ltEL->runID != runID) {
        traverse(ltEl);
      }
    }
      // current
    std::cout << *El;
      // successors
    for (auto& rtEl : el->right) {
      if (rtEL->runID != runID) {
        traverse(rtEl);
      }
    }
  }
}
```